# Do we say "most of + possessive + a noun"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, determiners

Someone asked the grammaticality of this sentence in our group:

> I liked the most our trip to Scotland.

Someone has tried to help. He wrote that the sentence could be fine if they removed "the" and add "of". However, he himself didn't seem to be sure with his correction.

> I liked most of our trip to Scotland.

Is the second highlighted sentence above even correct?

Comment: The actual article in adverbial "intensifier" ***[the] most*** is usually optional, but your second version above is completely different to the first because of the word ***of***. So #2 validly and idiomatically asserts that you liked *the greater part* of the trip (but **not all of it**; there were some parts you *didn't* like). But #1 is non-idiomatic because ***[the] most*** would normally be placed *after* the thing you liked most. *I liked our trip to Scotland [the] **most*** means that out of all the different things you did, going to Scotland was what you liked more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is grammatically correct. But it probably doesn't mean what the writer was trying to say with the first sentence.

"I liked most of our trip to Scotland" says that, of all the things we did on this trip, I liked most of them.

But "I liked the most our trip to Scotland", that's not grammatically correct, or at least is very awkward, but probably what the writer is trying to say is that, of all the things the group has done, the one he liked the most was the trip to Scotland.

The two ideas are very different. In the first case, the person might have liked most of the trip to Scotland, but still liked the trip to Wales more than he liked the trip to Scotland. Or if someone said that he liked the trip to Scotland the most, it might be that both trips were mediocre but the trip to Wales was even more boring than the trip to Scotland.

I'd reword the sentence to, "I liked our trip to Scotland the most".